# ActiveMQ recovery after connection loss or any excepiton

Tags: nms

So we have this logic for reading messages from queue:

```
///<inheritdoc/>
        public void ReceiveFromQueue<T>(IMessageHandler<T> callbackHandler, string queuePrefix, string consumer) where T : class, IMessageBase
        {
            if (callbackHandler == null)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"{nameof(ReceiveFromQueue)} error: {nameof(callbackHandler)} is null!");
                throw new MessageBusExcepiton($"{nameof(callbackHandler)} is null!", null);
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(queuePrefix))
            {
                _logger.LogError($"{nameof(ReceiveFromQueue)} error: {nameof(queuePrefix)} is null!");
                throw new MessageBusExcepiton($"{nameof(queuePrefix)} is Empty!", null);
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(queuePrefix))
            {
                _logger.LogError($"{nameof(ReceiveFromQueue)} error: {nameof(consumer)} is null!");
                throw new MessageBusExcepiton($"{nameof(consumer)} is Empty!", null);
            }

            try
            {
                //CREATE CONNECTION
                Uri uri = new Uri(_settings.BrokerUri);
                _logger.LogDebug($"{nameof(ReceiveFromQueue)} : Trying to create ActiveMQ factory [{_settings.BrokerUri}]");
                ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory(uri);

                IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection(_settings.Username, _settings.Password);

                _logger.LogDebug($"{nameof(ReceiveFromQueue)} : Trying to create session to ActiveMQ Broker [{_settings.BrokerUri}] for user [{_settings.Username}]");
                ISession session = connection.CreateSession(AcknowledgementMode.IndividualAcknowledge);

                IQueue dest = session.GetQueue(GenerateQueueName(queuePrefix, consumer));
                IMessageConsumer messageConsumer = session.CreateConsumer(dest);

                _logger.LogDebug($"{nameof(ReceiveFromQueue)} : Trying to start connection to ActiveMQ Queue [{dest.QueueName}]");
                connection.Start();

                //Add message handler for consuming messages
                messageConsumer.Listener += new MessageListener((receivedMsg) =>
                {
                    _logger.LogDebug($"Message received on [{dest.QueueName}]", receivedMsg);

                    //try to cast
                    var msg = receivedMsg as IObjectMessage;
                    var body = msg?.Body as T;

                    //In case of unsucessful cast or empty message body will be null
                    if(body == null)
                    {
                        var pMessage = new PoisonMessageModel() { Message = receivedMsg, MessageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Reason = $"Unsuccessful cast to {typeof(T)}" };
                        _logger.LogDebug($"Message failed on [{dest.QueueName}] for Reason: [\"Unsuccessful cast to {typeof(T)}\"]", receivedMsg);

                        //add poison message to queue
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        if (callbackHandler.Handle(body))
                        {
                            msg.Acknowledge();
                            _logger.LogDebug($"Message {body.MessageId} acknowledged on [{dest.QueueName}]");
                        }

                    } catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        var pMessage = new PoisonMessageModel() { Message = receivedMsg, MessageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Reason = e.Message };
                        _logger.LogError($"Message handle failed on [{dest.QueueName}] for Reason: [{e.Message}]", e);

                        //add poison message to queue
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (NMSSecurityException exc)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Error while communicating to ActiveMQ Service!", exc);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Error on {nameof(ReceiveFromQueue)}", e);
            }
        }
```

And our goal is to have continuous listener on queue which will get notified when there are some messages on queue.
We are using failover connection so I'm wandering if this is enough to cover network flickering and failure so that this listener will not stop?
How to do proper recovery in case of some errors? Do we need to register listener again or what is the best practice in that case?
This will be used from multiple different services.

Comment: What kind of client are you using? This looks like the NMS client. Can you confirm?

Comment: @JustinBertram Yes, it's NMS client